# Importing tesseract.js in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Im developing this chrome extensions and I want to use the `tesseract.js` library to recognize text in an image. Only im clueless on how to import the library. I am using manifest V3 so importing using the CDN link is not possible (as far as I read in the documentation). So I installed the library locally using `npm --save`, and then webpacked it with `npx webpack`, but I still cant get any off the functions imported.

I tried the options given by the tesseract.js documentation, which are:

```
import Tesseract from 'tesseract.js';

Tesseract.recognize(
  'https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png',
  'eng',
  { logger: m => console.log(m) }
).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
  console.log(text);
})
```

and

```
import { createWorker } from 'tesseract.js';

const worker = createWorker({
  logger: m => console.log(m)
});

(async () => {
  await worker.load();
  await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
  await worker.initialize('eng');
  const { data: { text } } = await worker.recognize('https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png');
  console.log(text);
  await worker.terminate();
})();
```

But neither work, because `tesseract.js` is not a valid file according to the service worker. As said above, I also tried importing it using the CDN link, but because of the CSP regulations, chrome can't import non-local libraries in Manifest V3 using links.
[in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLKyx.png) you can see the file structure. I copied some of the tesseract files from the `node_modules` folder into the `services` folder for easier access.

Can anyone explain to me how I am supposed to import `tesseract.js` on a chrome extension. Apparently its not as easy as just using `import Tesseract from 'tesseract.js';`

Comment: Service worker can't create nested workers, https://crbug.com/1219164. You'll have to do it in a visible html page.

Comment: I already tried doing it with a content script that runs on the current visible tab. But my problem is that I just cant get the tesseract.js library imported, I just keep getting reference errors, because tesseract is undefined, or import errors because chrome cant import the library or something

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what @wOxxOm meant with his reply,

> Service worker can't create nested workers, crbug.com/1219164. You'll have to do it in a visible html page.

but when I run the tesseract.min.js **AS** an content script, either by mentioning it in the manifest, or using `chrome.scripting.executeScript()`, `Tesseract` becomes a global variable for all content scripts on that page, and thus I can actually use it in my script. Either way thank you for your help